# Database ps statements Insertion

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Trying to insert a file like this into the database

Actor: Taylor Lautner

Bio: Taylor Daniel Lautner was born in Grand Rapids, Michigan to parents, Deborah and Daniel Lautner. He, and younger sister Makena, were raised in a well-mannered, Roman Catholic household in Hudsonville, Michigan. At the age of six, Taylor began studying martial arts at Fabiano"s Karate School and he, along with his family, quickly noticed his unique and natural talent for the sport. He was soon invited to train with seven-time world karate champion Michael Chaturantabut (aka Mike Chat) and, at the age of eight, he was asked to represent his country in the twelve years and under division in the World Karate Association where he became the Junior World Forms and Weapons champion, winning three gold medals. In 2003, Taylor continued to flourish in the martial arts circuit where he ranked number one in the world for NASKA"s Black Belt Open Forms, Musical Weapons, Traditional Weapons and Traditional Forms and, at the age of twelve, he became the three time Junior World Champion.

More_Bio: However, in addition to his love for martial arts, Taylor quickly developed a love for acting at the age of seven years old when his martial arts instructor, who was involved in show business, encouraged him to audition for a small appearance in a Burger King commercial. Although he was unsuccessful, he enjoyed the experience so much that he told his parents that he wanted to pursue a career in acting. Soon, he and his family were traveling back-and-forth from their home in Michigan to California so Taylor could audition for acting roles on a regular basis. When Taylor was ten, with the frequent traveling and air fares starting to become overwhelming, his family made the crucial decision to relocate to Los Angeles where Taylor would have the advantage of being able to audition for films, television, and commercials full-time.

Reason: This is one hunky teen idol! I loved him as Jacob Black in the "Twilight" series! He is one of the best-looking guys I"ve ever seen. I was so excited when I tweeted him and he replied back once!

Fact: He played football during his freshman and sophomore year of high school. He is of German, French, Dutch, and Native American (specifically Ottawa and Potawatomi) descent. Omg! And we both like the band Kings of Leon.

Actor: Robert Pattinson

Bio: He was born on May 13, 1986, in London, England. He enjoys music and is an excellent musician, playing both the guitar and piano. When Robert was 15, he started acting in amateur plays with the Barnes Theatre Company. Afterward, he took screen role like Curse of the Ring (2004) (TV) (Kingdom of Twilight) as Giselher.

More_Bio: In 2003, Robert took on the role of Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire (2005). He got his role a week later after meeting Mike Newell in late 2003. He has since been cast as Edward Cullen in the highly-anticipated film, Twilight (2008/I). His music will also be heard in the film. Additionally, Robert has completed upcoming roles as Salvador Dalí in Little Ashes (2008) and Art in How to Be (2008).

Reason : Quirky, Robert Pattinson took my breath away when I first saw him as Cedric Diggory in "Harry Potter," but stole my heart when I saw him as s vampire Edward Cullen in "Twilight." Team Edward For the Win!! I just love his messy hair and thick eyebrows.

Fact: : He is an excellent musician and plays both the guitar and piano. He began taking piano lessons at age three, and classical guitar at five.

This is the code to do the insertion

```
String Actor = "", Bio = "", More_Bio = "", Fact ="", Reason = "";
while ((it = br.readLine()) != null)   {

    if (it.startsWith("Actor: "))
    {
        it = it.replace("'", "\"");
         // remove actor
      it = it.replace("Actor:  ", " ");
         Actor = it;
         System.out.println(Actor);
        // ps.setString(1, Actor);
    }


    if (it.startsWith("Bio:"))
    {
        it = it.replace("'", "\"");
         // remove actor
      it = it.replace("Bio:  ", " ");
          Bio = it;
         System.out.println(Bio);
     //    ps.setString(2, Bio);
    }
    if (it.startsWith("More_Bio:"))
    {
        it = it.replace("'", "\"");
         // remove actor
      it = it.replace("More_Bio:  ", " ");
     More_Bio = it;
         System.out.println(More_Bio);
      //   ps.setString(3, More_Bio);
    }
    if (it.startsWith("Reason:"))
    {
        it = it.replace("'", "\"");
         // remove actor
      it = it.replace("Reason:  ", " ");
     Reason = it;
         System.out.println(Reason);
    //     ps.setString(4, Reason);
    }

    if (it.startsWith("Fact:"))
    {
        it = it.replace("'", "\"");
         // remove actor
      it = it.replace("Fact:  ", " ");
     Fact = it;
         System.out.println(Fact);
       //  ps.setString(5, Fact);
    }


    ps.setString(1, Actor);
    ps.setString(2, Bio);
    ps.setString(3, More_Bio);
    ps.setString(4, Reason);
    ps.setString(5, Fact);
    ps.executeUpdate(); 

}
ps.close();
con.close();
```

If the code has ps statements inside the loop, Information for Taylor Lautner and Robert Pattinson is inserted to the database twice, when i take it out of the while loop, only the last, Robert Pattinson  is inserted. Taylor is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to getting the data is wrong. What you're trying to do is execute an update statement each time you find an actor or a bio or any such keyword. This is wrong, you should try to gather all the information first and then execute an update.

I would suggest the following approach:

- Create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and fill up all the information about the actor in POJO through your while loop.  Maintain this in a map (*where your key might be the actor's name*)
- Then iterate through the map, retrieve the information from the POJO for each key and create a update statement and execute your command.

A sample code might be something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TextReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextReader().reader();
    }

    public void reader() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String it;
        String Actor = "", Bio = "", More_Bio = "", Fact = "", Reason = "";

        try {
            HashMap<String, PersonData> informationMap = new HashMap<String, TextReader.PersonData>();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("textFile.txt")));
            
            while ((it = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (it.startsWith("Actor: ")) {
                    it = it.replace("'", "\"");
                    // remove actor
                    it = it.replace("Actor:  ", " ");
                    Actor = it;
//                  System.out.println(Actor);
                    // ps.setString(1, Actor);
                }

                PersonData dataVO = informationMap.containsKey(Actor) ? informationMap.get(Actor) : new PersonData();

                if (it.startsWith("Bio:")) {
                    it = it.replace("'", "\"");
                    // remove actor
                    it = it.replace("Bio:  ", " ");
                    Bio = it;
                    // System.out.println(Bio);
                    dataVO.setBio(Bio);
                    // ps.setString(2, Bio);
                }
                if (it.startsWith("More_Bio:")) {
                    it = it.replace("'", "\"");
                    // remove actor
                    // it = it.replace("More_Bio:  ", " ");
                    More_Bio = it;
//                  System.out.println(More_Bio);
                     dataVO.setMoreBio(More_Bio);
                    // ps.setString(3, More_Bio);
                }
                if (it.startsWith("Reason:")) {
                    it = it.replace("'", "\"");
                    // remove actor
                    it = it.replace("Reason:  ", " ");
                    Reason = it;
                     dataVO.setReason(Reason);
                    // System.out.println(Reason);
                    // ps.setString(4, Reason);
                }

                if (it.startsWith("Fact:")) {
                    it = it.replace("'", "\"");
                    // remove actor
                    it = it.replace("Fact:  ", " ");
                    Fact = it;
                     dataVO.setFact(Fact);
                    // System.out.println(Fact);
                    // ps.setString(5, Fact);
                }

//              System.out.println(Actor + "\t" + Bio + "\t" + More_Bio + "\t"
//                      + Reason + "\t" + Fact);
                informationMap.put(Actor, dataVO);
            }
            
            for(String actorName: informationMap.keySet()){
                PersonData dataVO = informationMap.get(actorName);
                System.out.println(actorName);
                     // === Create your preparedstatement heare and execute the update ====
            }
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Your sample POJO class might look something like this:

```
    /**
     * Sample Person POJO class
     */
    public class PersonData {
        private String bio;
        private String moreBio;
        private String fact;
        private String reason;

        public String getBio() {
            return bio;
        }

        public void setBio(String bio) {
            this.bio = bio;
        }

        public String getMoreBio() {
            return moreBio;
        }

        public void setMoreBio(String moreBio) {
            this.moreBio = moreBio;
        }

        public String getFact() {
            return fact;
        }

        public void setFact(String fact) {
            this.fact = fact;
        }

        public String getReason() {
            return reason;
        }

        public void setReason(String reason) {
            this.reason = reason;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

- Java naming convention states that variable names should start with a lower case. Although I followed what you had in your code for consistency's sake, I would highly recommend that you refactor your variable names
- I've made one base assumption that your actor name would be unique. That is why I used it as a key in this case. If this is not true, then you might want to consider having the actor name as part of the POJO class and use another unique identifier as your key.